# Read HTML array using javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have array element in HTML

```js
<input type="checkbox" value="Value1" name="model[settings][]">
<input type="checkbox" value="Value2" name="model[settings][]">
<input type="checkbox" value="Value3" name="model[settings][]">
```

I am reading all the HTML input, iterating it and building a hash in the javascript. But this will read the array element and only pick the last model[settings][] element.

```js
var inputs = jQuery(" :input", "#elementID");
```

Is there a way in jQuery or JavaScript to read and build an array variable in javascript which then can be passed to controller ?

Thank You

Comment: why are you using same array name for checkboxes? For radios this is understandable but not for checkboxes

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to iterate through all your `input` elements to get their value and store that as a JS object, correct?
If that's the case, I would add a unique ID to all my inputs, and then create an object with the structure `{ id : value }`:

```js
function getInputObject(sel) {
  sel = $(sel);
  var out = {};
  sel.each(function() {
    out[$(this).attr("id")] = $(this).val();
  });
  return out;
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log( getInputObject("input") );
});
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input1" value="value input 1" type="text" />
<input id="input2" value="value input 2" type="text" />
<input id="input3" value="value input 3" type="text" />
```

Comment: So i would want to use the name of the HTML element,
i.e. name="model[something]", name="model[settings][]"

this will build a hash with its name when iterating it, 
i.e. data[inputs [i].name] = inputs [i].value;
but the array name has the same name and overwriting the existing value. so data[model[settings]] should be an array type when its being built instead of assigning data[model[settings][]].

Comment: In your example, all your names are identical, so your object will only contain one key with the value of the last input. But if your names are something like this: `model[settings][smth]` and `model[settings][smth-else]`, you would need to change this line: `out[$(this).attr("id")] = $(this).val();` to this: `out[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val();` Updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: After you last comment edit, I don't really follow what you are trying to accomplish. I'm sorry, but could you elaborate?

Comment: i would want to use `model[settings][]` name to build an object `data[model[settings]` with type array. 
Currently it iterates through all the input element and build `data[model[settings][]]` and kept on overwriting it due to the same name. 
Is there a way without using the id but just look at the name to check if it contains [] then build an object array ?

Comment: I see... So, if the element's name is simply `model[settings]`, it wouldn't make it into the array, but if it is `model[settings][]` or `model[settings][smth]` it would?

Comment: yes, it should make it an array if the name is `model[settings][]` posting directly to controller. But i am using ajax and the object is being built in javascript therefore only the last value of this is being read since its being iterated. 

if i have 4 elements `model[a], model[b], model[settings][], and model[settings][]`, the resulting javascript object is `data['model[a]'], data['model[b]'], and data['model[settings][]']` which is incorrect, it should be `data['model[a]'], data['model[b]'], and data['model[settings]']` with `model[settings]` key is an array type.

Comment: This does not take into account checked state and therefore doesn't reflect the real UI

Comment: I am using 1 column in database to store multiple checkboxes value, hence i need all the value in the array whether its checked on not checked. 
But i will separate the checkboxes into different columns for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: I'm sorry to insist on this, but I don't get why you would **"separate the checkboxes into different columns"**. If you have a form, say, with three checkboxes, assuming the order of those checkboxes remains the same on the dom for every page load, if you stored their checked states in a regular array, say, `(true, false, true)`, the key order would match that of the checkbox elements on the page, so it would just be a matter of iterating through them with a for loop and assign them their respective checked states. I don't see a need to store them by name or into different columns in your Db.

Comment: that would be one way to do that, storing it as an array in the db.